# Django - Template is not displaying the entire context list that I am passing

Tags: django, django-models, django-templates, django-views

This is driving me crazy. I ran my logic in the shell and the list I am filling is holding all the values that should be passed to the template but when the template is rendered it is only displaying the first pass of the "each_role" iteration

The shell shows 8 objects being placed into the list and all I am doing is passing that to be rendered in the template. The user I am using for both test cases is my admin user that is assigned to a 'finance' and 'IT' Role hence why it showed all 8 objects. The first 5 objects are 'IT' objects and the remaining 3 are the 'Finance'.

Any reason for this behavior and why it will not display all the lines on the webpage?
I attached an image of the actual page rendered. Thank yoU!
[WebPage image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0Myw.png)

### Shell

```
>>> for each_role in all_roles:
...     if each_role in user_roles:
...             list_of_reqs = RequisitionLine.objects.filter(assistance=each_role.id)
...             for line in list_of_reqs:
...                     parent = line.parent_req
...                     if parent in req_header_list:
...                             continue
...                     else:
...                             req_header_list.append(parent)
...             for i in range(len(req_header_list)):
...                     hold_line_count = RequisitionLine.objects.filter(Q(parent_req=req_header_list[i]) & Q(assistance=each_role.id))
...                     for j in hold_line_count:
...                             req_header_line_list.append(j)
...                             print(j)
...
RequisitionLine object (30)
RequisitionLine object (32)
RequisitionLine object (33)
RequisitionLine object (34)
RequisitionLine object (39)
RequisitionLine object (29)
RequisitionLine object (37)
RequisitionLine object (38)
>>>
>>> req_header_line_list
[<RequisitionLine: RequisitionLine object (30)>, <RequisitionLine: RequisitionLine object (32)>, <RequisitionLine: RequisitionLine object (33)>, <RequisitionLine: RequisitionLine object (34)>, <RequisitionLine: RequisitionLine object (39)>, <RequisitionLine: RequisitionLine object (29)>, <RequisitionLine: RequisitionLine object (37)>, <RequisitionLine: RequisitionLine object (38)>]
>>>
```

### Views.py

```
def assistance_list(request):

    req_header_list = []
    req_header_line_list = []

    user = CustomUser.objects.get(username=request.user)
    all_roles = UserRoles.objects.all() 
    user_roles = user.roles.all()

    for each_role in all_roles:
        if each_role in user_roles:
        # for u_role in user_roles:
            # if each_role == u_role:
            list_of_reqs = RequisitionLine.objects.filter(assistance=each_role.id)
            for line in list_of_reqs:
                parent = line.parent_req
                if parent in req_header_list:
                    continue 
                else:
                    req_header_list.append(parent)

            for i in range(len(req_header_list)):                                                    
                hold_line_count = RequisitionLine.objects.filter(Q(parent_req=req_header_list[i]) & Q(assistance=each_role.id))

                for j in hold_line_count:
                    req_header_line_list.append(j)

        return render(request, 'req/assist_req_list.html', {'req_header_line_list':req_header_line_list})
```

### assist_req_list.html

```
<h1>Assist Requisition</h1>

    <table>
            {% for requisition in req_header_line_list %}    
        <tr>
            <td>
                <a href="{% url 'requisition:assist_req_seq' requisition.parent_req.id requisition.sequence %}">{{ requisition }}</a>     
            </td>
        </tr>
        {% endfor %}
    </table>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an indentation error; your `return` is inside the outer for loop so will be triggered after the first iteration.

Comment: I knew it had to be something silly, Thank you for lending me your eyes I was going insane!